# Use Select-String to get the single word matching pattern from files

Tags: powershell, expression, select-string

I am trying to get only the word when using Select-String, but instead it is returning the whole string

```
Select-String -Path .\*.ps1 -Pattern '-Az' -Exclude "Get-AzAccessToken","-Azure","Get-AzContext"
```

I want to get all words in all .ps1 files that contain '-Az', for example 'New-AzHierarchy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs *objects* of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) by default, which supplement the whole *line* (input object) on which a match was found (`.Line` property) with metadata about the match (in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can use `-Raw` to directly output the matching lines (input objects) only).

  - Note that in the default *display* output, it appears that only the matching *lines* are printed, with PowerShell (Core) 7+ now highlighting the part that matched the pattern(s).
- `Select-String`'s `-Include` / `-Exclude` parameters do *not* modify what patterns are matched; instead, they modify the `-Path` argument to further narrow down the *set of input files*. Since a wildcard expression as part of the `-Path` argument is usually sufficient, these parameters are rarely used.

---

Therefore:

- Use the objects in the `.Matches` collection property `Select-String`'s output objects to access the *part of the line that actually matched* the given pattern(s).

  - Since you want to capture entire command names that contain substring `-Az`, such as `New-AzHierarchy`, you must use a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) pattern that also captures the relevant surrounding characters: `\w+-Az\w+`
- The simplest way to *exclude* specific matches is to filter them out *afterwards*, using a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call.

```bash
# Note: -AllMatches ensures that if there are *multiple* matches 
#        on a single line, they are all reported.
Select-String -Path .\*.ps1 -Pattern '\w+-Az\w+' -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
  Where-Object { $_ -notin 'Get-AzAccessToken', '-Azure', 'Get-AzContext' }
```